# What is the Moq syntax to change the behaviour at each call?

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I need an interface to return a certain value the first time an argument is passed but throw an exception for each subsequent call.

How can I do this ?

i.e. if I have such an interface:

```
namespace TradingInterface
{
    public interface IBackOffice
    {
        void Buy(string stock, int amount);
        void Sell(string stock, int amount);
    }
}
```

and the following mock object:

```
public class MockBackOffice: IBackOffice
{
    private bool _firstcall = true; 
    public void Buy(string stock, int amount)
    {
        if (_firstcall && stock == "AAPL")
        {
            _firstcall = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("second call");
        }
    }

    public void Sell(string stock, int amount)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I was to define the following, it would not throw on the second call of buy on "AAPL":

```
Mock<IBackOffice> mockBackOffice = new Mock<IBackOffice>();
mockBackOffice.Setup(x => x.Buy(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
var backOffice = mockBackOffice.Object;
```

How can I change the behaviour with Moq on the second call with certain arguments so it will throw an exception ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work if you actually need to mock the throw:

```
var firstCall = false;
mockBackOffice.Setup(x => x.Buy(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
              .Callback((string stock, int amount) => {
                  if (firstCall)
                      firstCall = false;
                  else
                      throw new InvalidOperationException("second call");
              });
```

If all you need is to verify the function was called at most one time, dwatland's answer is better.

Comment: EDIT: actually what you did Lucas is exactly what I need.

Comment: Of course, it's better if it does what you want. I misunderstood your question. I thought you really need the function to throw to test how some other code reacts to that.

Comment: Sorry actually I used both and I can see that your answer is actually the correct one, I need it to throw, apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You want the Verify method on the mockBackOffice. Use it like this:

```
mockBackOffice.Verify(x => x.Buy("AAPL", It.IsAny<int>()), Times.AtMostOnce());
```

This fails the unit test if the method in the lambda expression with the given parameters was not executed the specified number of times. Check the Verify section under the Moq documentation for more info: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart